# Python-How do I add a space for each odd numbered position in an array?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Essentially, I am inputting a certain number of Xs in an array. However, after that, I want to add a space after each X so that it goes from ['X','X','X','X'] to [X,' ',X,' ',X,' ',X] subject to how many spaces a user enters.

Any help would be appreciated, please.

```py
def two_numbers():

    array = []
    add_x = input('enter no. of x\'s: ')
    add_x = int(add_x)
    for i in range(0,add_x,1):
        array.append('X')


two_numbers()
```

Comment: Just to confirm, you are suggesting in your question that you want to double the number of items in your list, and change from a string object 'X' to the object X (presumably a number??)

Comment: There's no space after the last X in your example…

Comment: That's okay, it is not needed :)

Comment: @katardin So lets say the user wants 3 spaces but 4 Xs, therefore it would output ['X',' ','X',' ','X',' ','X']

Comment: Why are the Xs gone from 'X' in the first array to X in the second? Did you forget to put the quotes around the Xs in the second array?

Answer (score 0):

Just you can append the statement once again.

```
array = []
add_x = input('enter no. of x\'s: ')
add_x = int(add_x)
for i in range(0,add_x,1):
     array.append('X')
     array.append(" ")


# Multiply the space by the number of spaces you want to append each time.
# array.append(" "*1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You'll need to `del` the last element with that method.

Answer (score 0):

Since you specifically want odd numbered positions with a space, you could do this:

```
def two_numbers():

    array = []
    add_x = input('enter no. of x\'s: ')
    add_x = int(add_x)
    for i in range(0,add_x,1):
        # Add space if array length is even.
        if len(array) % 2 == 1:
            array.append(' ')
        array.append('X')

two_numbers()

# ['X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X']
```

Comment: Hey this is really helpful, thank you! Do you know how I could add some functionality, whereby if the user wanted two spaces, it would only append a space at positions 1 and 3 e.t.c I'm trying to figure that out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @AnUnknownStudent `for _ in range(number_of_spaces_wanted): array.append(" ")`

Comment: @AnUnknownStudent you can place the "array.append('X')" right before the "if len(array) % 2 == 1"

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner:

```py
num_x = 4
output = list(' '.join('X' * num_x))

print(output)
>>> ['X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [str.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
add_x = input('enter no. of x\'s: ')
# input 3
array = list(' '.join('X' * add_x)
print(array)
```

output:

```
['X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X']
```

one-line solution:

```
array = list(' '.join('X' * int(input('enter no. of x\'s: '))))
```

or:

```
array = (['X', ''] * int(input('enter no. of x\'s: ')))[:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

just to add other solutions to the ones already here.

```
import itertools

def two_numbers(n):
    tmp = zip(['X' for _ in range(n)], [' ' for _ in range(n) ])
    return list(itertools.chain(*tmp))
```

or

```
def two_numbers(n):
    array = []
    for _ in range(n):
        array += ['X', ' ']
    return array
```

The returned lists will terminate with a `' '`, if you want to you can remove it by calling the `pop` method of the list or by returning a slice (e.g. `return array[:-1]` )

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Here is a **one-line solution** to what you want to do.

```py
n = 8 # number of X's
(['X', ' ']*n)[:-1]
```

**Output**:

```
['X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X', ' ', 'X']
```

### Equivalent Other Method(s)

```py
# Method-1
nrep = 5
','.join(['X, ']*nrep)[:-2)].split(',') 

# Method-1 wrapped as a convenience function
def patterned_array(nrep:int = 5, sep = ' ', base_string = 'X') -> list:
    spattern = ''.join([base_string, sep])
    return ','.join(spattern*n)[:-len(spattern)].split(',')

# generate patterned array (a list)
patterned_array(nrep = 8)
```

## Insert a space-character in between elements of an existing list

What if you already have a list of items and they are not necessarily all the same? You could insert a desired character in between those elements in the list as follows.

```py
array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
bigarray = [' ']*(len(array)-1)
for i, e in enumerate(array): bigarray.insert(2*i, e)
bigarray
```

**Output**:

```
['a', ' ', 'b', ' ', 'c', ' ', 'd', ' ', 'e']
```

Comment: @AnUnknownStudent let me know if this helps.